# How do i remove a div on hover?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, react-state

I'm using tailwind css and i want a user to be able to view the background image when they hover on an icon i'll have on the top left. Is there a way i can apply hidden class to a div only when a user hovers on that icon?

Answer (score 0):

we can use pseudo elements for this:

`class2{display:none;}`

`class1:hover class2   { display:block; }`